# Pointer to function for glutDisplayFunc

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to make 3 windows to represent rotation around the given axis.
For that I made a class `XYZAxis` which contain function `render`.
Next, from the main I call the function `creatWindow` which makes a GLUT window.
However I don't know how to correctly pass function render to `glutDisplayFunc` :(
fragment of main

```
void (XYZAxis::* pmf)(void);
pmf = &XYZAxis::render;

XYZAxis *xaxis=&XYZAxis(origin,5,10);


glutDisplayFunc( void(xaxis->*pmf)() ) ;
glutIdleFunc(void(xaxis->*pmf)());
```

and a function within XYZAxis class

```
void render(void) 
{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();



this->orientation=this->orientation*(this->angle);
this->draw();

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

the program compiles however when it reaches the `glutMainLoop()`;
it throws an error and closes the window

> GLUT: Warning in (unamed): The following is a new check for GLUT 3.0; update
>   your code.
>   GLUT: Fatal Error in (unamed): redisplay needed for window 1, but no display
>   callback.

how to do it correctly?any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can pass a pointer to a C++ instance method to a C API like GLUT.  You will need to wrap the method call in a C function using a global pointer to the instance you are interested in.  See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html